# Error presentViewController - view controllers adding - objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uiviewcontroller

I have a problem and can't know the reason or solution
I have AddDelegate and another ViewController, in this ViewController I add FBFriendPickerViewController, and ViewController will be added to AppDelegate ..

I add ViewController to AppDelegate like this: ( this ViewController is SocialSharing class )

```
if( socialSharing == nil )
    socialSharing = [[SocialSharing alloc] init];

[_window.rootViewController.view addSubview:socialSharing.view];
```

And add FBFriendPickerViewController in ViewController(SocialSharing) like this:

```
-(void)shareOnFaceBook:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    if( shareOnUserOrFriendWallBtnIndex == 0 )
    {

    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

        SLComposeViewController *facebookSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        NSURL *candidateURL = [NSURL URLWithString:contentDataToShare];

        if (candidateURL && candidateURL.scheme && candidateURL.host) {
            [facebookSheet setInitialText:@"See this link .."];
            [facebookSheet addURL:candidateURL];
        }
        else // Event ***
        {
            [facebookSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",[[appDelegate.extrasOverlayView.markerData.btnsArr objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"markerName"],@" .. \n", contentDataToShare]];
            [facebookSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:lastVideoLink]];
        }

        //Brings up the little share card with the test we have pre defind.
        [appDelegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController:facebookSheet animated:YES completion:nil];

    } else {
        //This alreat tells the user that they can't use built in socal interegration and why they can't.
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"You can't send a tweet right now, make sure you have at least one Facebook account setup and your device is using iOS." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }

}
else if( shareOnUserOrFriendWallBtnIndex == 1 )// post on friend's wall
{
    if ( [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://"]] )
    {
        NSLog(@"Facebook is inastalled on this device.");
        if( friendPickerController == nil )
        {
            friendPickerController = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
            friendPickerController.delegate = self;

            if( !( [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone ) )
                friendPickerController.title = @"Select Friends";
        }

        [friendPickerController loadData];


        // Present view controller modally
        [self presentViewController:friendPickerController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"This device has no Facebook app.");
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"You can't invite friends, Facebook app isn't installed, please install it and retry again." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }

}
```

}

and dismiss friendPickerController from SocialSharing like:

```
- (void)facebookViewControllerCancelWasPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Friend selection cancelled.");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I used:

```
[friendPickerController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   OR //[self.view.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
OR //[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

It works good for only first time, once, friendPickerController appears and dismiss when close, BUT when call to open again, I have this error:

"Thread 1: signal SIGBRT"

FOR the line of :

```
[self presentViewController:friendPickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Note: when I add friendPickerController on AppDelegate directly (in class of AppDelegate) without another class (here is SocialSharing ViewController), it works great ..

I'm working on IOS 7, and Facebook SDK 3.13..
So, What is the problem, How can I solve it ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you check if friendPickerController is not nil the second time you try to present it?

Comment: every time friend picker object having value so it will not present a once again.For that create object for friend picker in your view load or nil your object to process more time

Comment: @Zhang, thank you for reply, already I check if it's nil by if( friendPickerController == nil ), this code is called every time to show it

Comment: @karthikeyan, thank you for reply, what do mean about "every time friend picker object having value so it will not present a once again" ? what is value you mean?, also, Do you mean that I should set friendPickerController = nil every time and realloc and init to present it?

Comment: show me your full code for button click..thi line first time only nil  if( friendPickerController == nil ) if you done this in button click..next time this condition will not true.

Comment: @karthikeyan, I updated my question with all method of present and dismiss, I know that this condition won't be true, why i need to realloc friendPickerController and init every time?, I'm new in objective c, so Is it good to realloc object every time i call?

Comment: better allocate a friend picker class somewhere else in your view load      and remove condition from button click action.

Comment: I tried now to realloc it every time, but problem become that its buttons have no effect, i add two buttons to friendPickerController, SelectAll and ClearAll,this btns now can't change in friendPickerController selection friends, it works great if in AppDelegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to solve my problem, I create friendPickerController in NORMAL CLASS , NOT ViewController, and add it on AppDelegate

```
     [appDelegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController:friendPickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and dismiss by:

```
    [appDelegate.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

And call this Class like:

```
if( socialSharing == nil )
{
    socialSharing = [[SocialSharingClass alloc] init];
    [socialSharing initSocialSharing];
}
```

Still, I don't know the problem, but that solved it. May that help anyone.